# Speed up data load to data grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

I have following control and its data binding. I am loading only 30 records per page over here though it takes 4 to 5 seconds to load 30 records.

Xaml:

```
<telerik:RadGridView 
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="preview" 
            EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}"
            MaxHeight="1600"
            MaxWidth="2560"
            />
```

.cs:

```
    private void GetData(int pageIndex)
            {
                try
                {
                    //get data
                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from bseg limit " + (pageIndex-1)*30 + ", " + 30, conn);

                    conn.Open();

                    var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                    dataTable.Load(rdr);

                    **preview.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView;**
//This line is taking a long time. 3 to 4 seconds.

                    conn.Close();

                    //get number of records in table
                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("select count(*) from bseg;", conn);

                    conn.Open();

                    numOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

                    numOfPages = numOfRecords / numberOfRecPerPage;

                    lblTotalPages.Content = " of " + numOfPages.ToString();

                    conn.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

In the above scenario, I am adding custom paging and loading only 30 records per page. For every next page, by using page index I am loading next 30 records. But I don't know why it takes 4 to 5 seconds to load data.

Comment: Which line is taking time?

Comment: I just check for GetData method.

Comment: preview.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView; This line is taking 3 to 4 seconds.

Comment: In that case, Just set the data context only once. Why not using ObservableCollection<T>. Mvvm approach will be better for databound application.

Comment: Also, it looks like you count the number of total records in the database every time you get another page of data. This has a cost.

Comment: And you could parameterize your `MySqlCommand`. May improve the odds that your database would cache the query plan.

Comment: Ohhh. I can separate count the number of total records. But How can I use ObservableCollection<T> if the structure of the table is unknown in advance?  Suggest some way!

Comment: Why would the structure of a table on which you have SQL select rights ever be unknown to you?

Comment: You need to use ObservableCollection<T> as your data source for the grid and each time clear it and load the new items into it.
Also you can fetch the whole data and using simple C# commands load into the ObservableCollection<T> only the items you wish to show.

Comment: I am confused bit of here, how to handle <T> over here!

Comment: Just FYI `IsAsync` in your `Binding` is not doing anything at all, if you want it to be `Async` you need to return a different type for your collection. More info [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn605875.aspx).